# How do I turn off vscode Settings Sync (request to log in to a Microsoft account)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Strangely there is lots of information on how to turn it on and log in but for me I have spent quite some time searching and can find no way to turn it off!

The information under: [How do I delete my data?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync#_how-do-i-delete-my-data) does not help me as there is no checkbox I can see.

> If you want to remove all your data from our servers, just turn off sync via the Manage gear menu and select the checkbox to clear all cloud data. If you choose to re-enable sync, it will be as if you're signing in for the first time.

Whenever I use vscode there is a handy blue number that indicates when a new update is available.  Now that number is always 1 and is 2 when there is an update.

The reason for the blue number 1 now is that it wants me to sign in to microsoft.  It would be great if I could stop vscode asking for a sign in to Microsoft.

Sorry if I have missed something obvious.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [How do I delete my data?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync#_how-do-i-delete-my-data)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94927:

> It was only by searching the github issues that I learned to use
>   cmd-shift-p and type "Preferences Sync" to find the disable command.

I am not able to test this since I turned on `Settings Sync` and so the badge notification went away for that reason.

Comment: At this moment, this option does not exist.

Comment: VSCode 1.80 released on 2023-07-04, this option is not available.

Answer (score 19):

1. Click on the bottom left gear icon, then click 'Settings Sync is On'

[image]

2. On the top list open, click 'Settings Sync: turn Off'

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way that I've found to turn off settings sync in VSCode is to use `CTRL + Shift + P` (Windows) or `CMD + SHIFT + P` (Mac) to open the settings palette.

Once opened up, search "`sync`" and there is a section called "`Settings Sync: Turn Off`" (if it's on).

Click that, and it will confirm that you want to turn it on or off. This will also stop the notification about syncing that comes up.

Answer (score 2):

For the MacOS, if you "turn off" and "delete user data" in Github the authentication data persists when you turn on sync again.

The authentication data is kept in the MacOS keychain, in the "System Keychains" under the name "vscodevscode.github-authentication".

For some reason, I was not allowed to delete this entry as an administrator. To break the connection with VSCode:

```
- you have to "Get Info" for the entry
- then under the "Access Control" tab 
- in the "Always allow access by these applications" section at the bottom, click "Visual Studio Code" and click the "-" icon at the bottom
```

Now you can sign in with another Github account!

BONUS: If you want to share VSCode settings with a team, create a generic company email "device@company.com" and Github account, and use that account for sharing common settings.

Answer (score 0):

The key is first you need to sign in an account first. Then you can turn off setting sync.

I was stuck when I was trying to switch to a new account. I log off my old account with microsoft. Then VS code does not have the option for me to select a new account with github.

Answer (score 0):

> This is for windows. For Mac use Command key in place of ctrl

```
    1. Ctrl + Shift + P
    2. Type -> sync
    3. Settings sync -> Turn off
```

Answer (score -1):

Ctrl + Shift + P -> Sync: Reset Extention Settings